# Prove that the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of a triangle meet at a point

Tags: geometry, proof-verification

Self-studying “Basic Mathematics” by Serge Lang, got stuck doing final problem of chapter 5.

[image]

I took a sample triangle and labeled two lines and points.

[image]

As L1 is the perpendicular bisector of segment PQ, I know KP = KQ. Points K, Q and M form a right triangle.

That’s the information I gathered, do not know how to proceed from there. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would caution you that you should draw a very general triangle $\triangle PQM$. Yours is isosceles and almost equilateral. Make it very generic, or else you'll be led to all sorts of false lines of reasoning.

Comment: It's not just that KP=KQ for that specific point K.  Any point X on L1 satisfies XP=XQ.  So what can you say about the points on L2 and L3?  And what can you say about the point where they meet?

Comment: Thank you @Ted Shifrin. How do I draw a generic triangle?

Comment: Will try to come up with an answer, @Matthew Daly.

Comment: @F.Zer A very philosophical question. Practically, when I want to make sure that I won't be misled, I try to draw a scalene triangle where none of the angles are right. In a sense that can be made precise, almost all triangles fit this description, so it's probably a good starting point. In general, a "generic" version of something is a version that has no unnecessary symmetry (like congruent sides) and no unnecessary "special" features (like a right angle).

Comment: The lines shouldn't go through the vertices.  That's very misleading as they don't in general.

Comment: the way you drew it it looks like KO and OM are colinear.  They almost certainly aren't.  OM is *not* part of line 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $L_1$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{PQ}$, it is also the line containing the altitude of $\triangle OPQ$ that passes through $O$ (since it is on $L_1$ as it is the intersection of $L_1$ and $L_2$).  As such, $d(O,P)=d(O,Q)$ since they are the two equal sides of an isosceles triangle.

Apply the similar approach for $L_2$.  Since $L_2$ is the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{QM}$, it is also the line containing the altitude of $\triangle OQM$ that passes through $O$.  As such, $d(O,Q)=d(O,M)$.

The transitive property therefore tells us $d(O,P)=d(O,M)$.

Note:  you may have to apply more algebra if you need a more rigourous explanation.

---

More info:  $O$ in this case is also called the *circumcentre* (the center of the circumscribed circle for the triangle).

Comment: Thank you. Could the explain the meaning of “altitude” of △ ?

Comment: The altitude of a triangle from a vertex is the straight-line distance from the vertex to the opposite side length.  The altitude that passes through $O$ is the line segment that touches $O$ and meets $\overline{PQ}$ at a right angle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Did you meant “Since 2 is the perpendicular bisector of ” ? Also, how did you spot they were isosceles triangles?

Comment: You can try this for yourself: perpendicularly bisect a line segment $\overline{AB}$ using a line $L$, then pick any point $P$ on $L$. $ABP$ is an isosceles triangle since $d(A,P)=d(B,P)$.

Comment: Perfect. I see now that two sides are equal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to offer a solution in the context of Lang's own presentation. This question is expecting one to use the Corollary to the Pythagoras Theorem that Lang provided on pg128. The proof of this corollary is on pg128 and exercise 9 from the same section.

[Serge Lang Perpendicular Bisector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TDJN.png)

We know that:

- if M lies on the perpendicular bisector *PQ*, then *d(P,M) = d(Q,M)*. (Proven in ex9 using pythag.)

SO, since *L<sub>1</sub>* is the perpendicular bisector of *PQ*, and *O* is on *L<sub>1</sub>*, ***d(P,O) = d(Q,O)*.**

The same goes for *L<sub>1</sub>* and having *O* on that line as well: since *L<sub>2</sub>* is the perpendicular bisector of *QM*, and *O* is on *L<sub>2</sub>*, ***d(Q,O) = d(M,O)*.**

We have: ***d(Q,O) = d(M,O)* and *d(P,O) = d(Q,O)*** from our assumptions of *L<sub>1</sub>* and *L<sub>2</sub>*.
Therefore, ***d(O,P) = d(O,M)* from the transitive property.** This relation ensures that *O* lies on the perpendicular bisector of *PM* because, as Lang proved on pg128:

- Given two distinct points on the plane, P and Q, let M also be a point on the plane, *d(P,M) = d(Q,M)* if and only if M lies on the perpendicular bisector of *PQ*.

So, since we have *d(O,P) = d(O,M)*, we know *O* must lie on the perpendicular bisector of *PM*.

Therefore, the perpendicular bisectors of the sides of the triangle *PQM*, defined by the set of segments *PQ, QM, PM*, meet in a point, in this case point *O*.

Answer (score 0):

We can see that $\triangle OKQ \cong \triangle OKP$ because $KQ=KP$, $KO$ is a common side and $\angle OKQ \cong \angle OKP$. Thus, $PO=OQ$. Apply the same reasoning to show that $OQ=OM$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *definition* of perpendicular bisector that the perpendicular bisector of $AB$ is all the points $X$ so that $AX = XB$.  You don't need to find any congruent triangles.

Because $L_1$ is perp bisector of $PQ$ we have $OP = OQ$.

Because $L_2$ is perp bisector of $QM$ we have $OQ = OM$.

So $OP = OM$.

Therefore $O$ is a point on the perp bisector of $MP$.

That's all there is to it.